# WPF - Define Window Icon inside a Custom Style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, icons, styles

I'm having troubles with the `Window` icon.

I've created my own `Style` for the `Windows` that is contained in a .xaml file inside the project. What I would like to do is to show the system `Icon` at the left corner of the `Window`. Usually, working directly on the `Window` I can set the `Icon` specifing it in the `Icon` property. But it's not working because the `Window` uses my own `Style` where the icon is not defined. So I tried to add the `Setter` for the `Icon` property inside my style:

```
<Style x:Key="KavoWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
        <Setter.Value>
            <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="30"
                          GlassFrameThickness="0"
                          CornerRadius="0"
                          NonClientFrameEdges="None"
                          ResizeBorderThickness="5"
                          UseAeroCaptionButtons="False"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="MyIcon.ico"/>      <==================
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#2ECC71"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#646464"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="1">
                        <AdornerDecorator>
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </AdornerDecorator>
                    </Border>

                    <DockPanel Height="30"
                               VerticalAlignment="Top"
                               LastChildFill="False">
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                                   Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                   FontSize="14"
                                   Foreground="#E8E8E8"
                                   Text="{TemplateBinding Title}"
                                   FontFamily="Open Sans Regular"/>

                    </DockPanel>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But it's not working (I get an exception when I run the program). I don't know if this is the right way to do it, and if not, I would like to know what is the right approach. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you marked icon as resource in property?

Comment: @Mohit If you are talking about the File Properties of the .ico, yes, it's marked as Resource in 'Build Action'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to place the icon somewhere in your custom title bar.

For example you can put an `Image` left of your `TextBlock`:

```
<DockPanel Height="30"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        LastChildFill="False">
    <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Icon}" />
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
        DockPanel.Dock="Left"
        Margin="5,0,0,0"
        FontSize="14"
        Foreground="#E8E8E8"
        Text="{TemplateBinding Title}"
        FontFamily="Open Sans Regular"/>    
</DockPanel>
```

Now it should be shown. Please adapt the size and layout to fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you, it was exactly what I was looking for!